# Хотелось бы знать, разумно будет спрашивать "как оно"

Tags: выбор-слов

Здравствуйте. Подскажите откуда уместно ли употреблять выражение "как оно?", откуда оно появилось и грамотно ли будет использовать его?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Это несколько небрежное, добродушно-просторечное выражение используется обычно сразу после приветствия в значении "как оно, твоё житьё-бытьё?" вместо широко распространённого "как жизнь?"

Употреблять его, конечно, можно, но в неформальной обстановке и только в отношении хорошо знакомых вам лиц, которых такое выражение точно не обидит.

Answer (score 1):

**Как оно там** - это обычно неполное предложение, которое можно дополнить различными вариантами по смыслу. Используется   в разговорной речи, также встречается в текстах как классиков, так и современных писателей, например:

Это уже не Джульетта, а какая-то Анжелика маркиза ангелов или **как оно там**.

Валерий Осипович, давайте прикинем, **как оно там**.

Папаша, ты нынче, кажись, о мире не говорил? **Как оно там?** не слыхать ничего?

А черт его знает, **как оно там…** [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Дневник провинциала в Петербурге (1872)].

Ну, а я «Маланьи» не писал и никакой земли безвозмездно не отдавал, а потому, **как оно там** ― не знаю. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин].

А господь его знает **как оно там** выйдет! [И. С. Тургенев. Разговор на большой дороге (1851)].

Answer (score 0):

В указанной в вопросе обособленной форме "как оно?", данное выражение является просторечием на грани сленга. Соответсвенно его можно использовать в разговорной речи (в соответствующей неформальной, а скорее даже панибратской атмосфере общения), но литературным данное выражение не является.

Answer (score 0):

Вопросительное выражение "(ну) как оно?" - чисто разговорное, но его нельзя назвать признаком косноязычия. Я не стал бы его относить и к просторечиям, поскольку им пользуются многие и в ряде ситуаций оно выполняет полезную указательную функцию: если люди, находящиеся в доверительных отношениях, о чём-то условились, то нет короче и конфиденциальней вопроса, позволяющего выяснить текущее состояние дела, которым оба озабочены с момента последнего общения. Адресат в таких случаях знает, что "оно" кратко обозначает "то, о чём они с собеседником условились", то есть, заменяет целый оборот. И это точнее вопроса "ну как", не содержащего указательного элемента.